# MacBook pro keeps shutting down

Tags: macbook-pro, shutdown

I have a 17" Macbook Pro from late 2011 and recently it's been shutting down randomly, but almost always when I try to move the machine. Nowadays it's happening once every few hours and it makes it very hard to use the machine.

```
Model Name: MacBook Pro 
Model Identifier: MacBookPro8,3 
Processor Name: Intel Core i7 
Processor Speed: 2.4 GHz 
Number of Processors: 1 
Total Number of Cores: 4 
L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB 
L3 Cache: 6 MB 
Memory: 4 GB
```

I'm hoping people can tell me what to do. I have AppleCare till March 19th, 2015

Comment: Take it back to Apple.

Comment: Please give us more information. Does it shutdown when using battery or AC power, or both? Does it get hot/do your fans work? Does it shutdown every time it's moved? The more info you can give us the better we can help ;-)

Comment: @ScunnerDarkly - Shuts down on both, it usually does get pretty hot, fans do work just cleaned the vents out and it's still happening. Won't shut down every time it's moved but pretty consistently. Hope this helped, thanks for your time